# How to use smart pointers with setUserData(void*)?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

is it possible to use c++11 smart pointers with nodes user data? has anyone tried it before?

```
node->setUserData(void* usrData);
node->getUserData();
```

**Solved:**

i figured a way to store objects in a Node without having to delete theme manually(gets automatically deleted when the Node is destroyed) and it might not be the best solution but it is a solution nevertheless, it involves inheriting from **cocos2d::Ref** class and using nodes **setUserObject(Ref* ptr)!**

this is how i made it happen:

1)- make a class/struct that inherits from cocos2d::Ref class.

2)- fill it with your custom properties and methods.

3)- make sure the object calls autorelease().

```
struct Box : public cocos2d::Ref
{
    // some properties here

    Box() {
        //autorelease means let other Nodes retain and release this object.
        //if you don't call autorelease then the object destructor won't get called which means in turn object memory is not released.
        this->autorelease();
    }

    ~Box() {
        //just to check if the object destructor is called or not.
        log("=========================");
        log("Box is destroyed"); 
        log("=========================");
    }

};
```

4)- make an object instance and put its pointer in any Node UserObject like this:

```
auto box = new Box;
this->setUserObject(box);// am putting it in the Layer UserObject
```

now the box object will be destroyed automatically whenever the Layer/Node is destroyed (no delete is needed)

PS: you should properly exit the cocos2d-x app in order for the nodes(Node, Layer, Scene) destructors to be called so can nodes children be destructed properly(children destructors are called) ... just press the back button if your in an emulator or use a close button that calls Director::end().

Comment: If the function is not declared to take a smart pointer, then no not really. You *can* use smart pointers, and then pass the actual pointer to the function, *but* that will risk the stored pointer becoming a stray pointer if the smart pointer decides to delete its contained pointer, and it really goes against the whole point (pun not intended) of using smart pointers to begin with.

Comment: so even if i use shared_ptr::get() method with setUserData ... the smart pointer will still get deleted?but what's the point of shared smart pointers any way if it still gonna delete its pointer even if a node userdata is holding on to it?

Comment: If you use e.g. `some_share_ptr.get()` to get the raw pointer, how would the shared pointer be able to keep track of the raw pointer? It just can't, and so when all shared pointers go out of scope the pointer will be deleted leaving you with a stray pointer.

Comment: but what if i used setUserData(&some_share_ptr) will it still be deleted?

Comment: That's no better than using the raw pointer from the shared pointer object. Using a pointer to a shared pointer object doesn't modify the shared pointer objects reference counter which it uses to keep track of the shared pointers objects.

Comment: i just want to put an object in userdata and not have to worry about its life time and i certainly don't want to use delete!

Comment: Unfortunately it's simply not possible.

Comment: big thanks for your clarifications and pardon me for my ignorance when it comes to smart pointers!

Answer (score 1):

This was a comment, but got too long.

I wouldn't see it as hopeless as @Joachim Pileborg does in the comments (although his points are true in principle). The only thing you have to assume is that `setUserData` is only observing, i.e. it performs no memory-related actions and particularly no `delete`.

You can then either simply use a smart pointer "outside",

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<some_object>();
node->setUserData(ptr.get());
```

Now, if the program then exits in a proper way, at least you don't have to manually delete `ptr`. But, as mentioned by Joachim, of course you have to make sure that `ptr` lives as long as it is might be used inside `node`.

Alternatively, you can write small wrapper around the `node` class which contains a `shared_ptr<void> ptr` variable and which offers a `setUserData(shared_ptr<void>)` method. If this method is invoked, it first copies the shared pointer and internally calls `node->setUserData(ptr.get())` method. Then the underlying object is guaranteed to stay alive.

Comment: but whats the point here in storing the pointer in user data if it's gonna be released the moment ptr leaves the scope?

Comment: @Joseph: the point (in the first alternative) is to make sure the smart pointer doesn't leave scope as long as you use it. But if it should by some exception, it still performs the task of `delete`-ing it properly. If your sceptical whether you can keep the pointer alive, use the second alternative: wrap everything inside a class which stores the smart pointer (and by this ensures it's alive). This is very similar to your solution approach, but maybe a bit more generic (one CRTP class suffices, instead of having to apply your solution for each class anew).

Comment: since cocos2d is open source i find one of the other solutions is to overload setuserdata() (since its virtual) and make it accept smart pointers like suggested by @davidhigh.